# Informatica server (shared network hosted on NTTData) Pythonic connection to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, informatica, google-cloud-composer, informatica-cloud

I need to connect my Informatica server (specific folder in a shared network) to Google Cloud Storage to download and upload files both ways.

I cannot use any UIs because I want to automate this task using Airflow (Composer) later on.

I am new and could not find any code snippets to help me with it.
I am looking for a Pythonic solution.

I would apprentice if you can help me and share some links or possible code snippets with me.

Comment: is it related to informatica tool?

Comment: It is for Informatica cloud.

Comment: After searching for it, I don't think this option exists yet. For the time being, the best I could find was [here](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-data-integration-connectors/current-version/google-cloud-storage-connector/introduction-to-google-cloud-storage-connector/google-cloud-storage-connector-overview.html). Here in the right you can see a Download Guide button, which has the most comprehensive guide I've found about it, but it doesn't mention automating the process with python.

Comment: Hello @hediehmoradi, a working solution would be to use the [gsutil rsync command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) in order to synchronize the files from each storage. You should point to the GCS bucket in one URL and to the Informatica server in the other one. You could also automate this with Composer by using [Airflow BashOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html).

Comment: @bernatj Thank you so much for spending time and searching for it. I do think you are correct. I will start look into it.